# Does Cordova accept <script src="myfile.js"> out of the <head>?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

Sorry for the script in the title, i dont know how spell that in english (spanish is my native language).

I am working on an APP, so I have a menu based on jQuery and one big script that calculate some data that will be displayed in the screen.

I have a very simple "LightBox" or "Modal Box" to display some info.

So... in a browser all the APP is fully functional, but when I built the APK file, Cordova does not recognize the link (in the footer) to the JS file that is used to run the modal box.

My question is if there is some special setup for this or is needed to set the  in the head obligatoirement ?

Sorry for my english! I hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards!

Comment: Did you really put it in as `<link src="myfile.js">`? Because it should be `<script src="myfile.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer RGraham... is just an error doing the question, all the code works perfectly in the PC....

Comment: Where is `myfile.js` stored? Local device or remote? Can you put the HTML into the question and let us know what version of Android & Cordova you're using?

Comment: Is stored locally... all the code have more than 700 lines, I dont know if is possible o correct to paste on the question, I am new on StackOverFlow... Android API is number 19.. I don't know wich version of Cordova is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put inside  or , cordova will load

But keep you js file inside www folder and give relative url:

ex: `<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src=".sencha/app/microloader/development.js"></script>`

Comment: it was with a relative url... seems that cordova is sensitive for upper and lower case  in the URL path

Answer (score 0):

you can put `<script>` any where inside the `<head`> tag and `<body>` tag. It will Sure shot Work...